# Need help understanding instance variables

Tags: java

I have these instance variables in my class:

```
private int x1 = 0;
private int y1 = 0;
private int x2 = 0;
private int y2 = 0;
private int height = y2 - y1;
private int width = x2 - x1;
```

In my program I use methods that change the `x`s and `y`s, so I expect `height` and `width` to change as well. However, they don't. Can someone explain why this is the case, and how I can make their values "update" after a method call that changes the `x`s and `y`s?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your expression `private int height = y2 - y1;` is evaluated when the instance variable is initialised: i.e. when the class is instantiated. From that point on it is does nothing - it is not "linked" in any way to the source parts of the expression and does not update when they update.

You probably want a method on the class (`public` if it is used outside the class, `private` otherwise) which would be something like the below. You can get rid of your `height` and `width` fields:

```
public int getHeight() { return this.y2 - this.y1; }
```

However if you decide you still need the width and height internally I would change this to a `private` method named `calculateHeight`. Methods called `getXYZ` are usually accessors for fields and not mutation methods. You can then call this (or the equivalent `calculateWidth()`) whenever you change the field values for `y2, y1, x2, x1`.

```
public int getHeight() { return this.height; }
private int calculateHeight() { return this.y2 - this.y1; }
...
this.y2 = this.y2 + 10;
this.height = calculateHeight();
```

As an aside I would argue that width and height are positive numbers regardless of `y2` being more or less than `y1`. You can use [`Math.abs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs(int)) to remove the sign on the subtraction result:

```
public int getHeight() { return Math.abs(y2 - y1); }
```

My preference would be to use a single method to return the height and width as a dimension. The two values are really a single piece of data at a point in time. You could use [java.awt.Dimension](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dimension.html) for this:

```
public Dimension getDimension() {
  new Dimension(Math.abs(x2 - x1), Math.abs(y2 - y1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your calculations are only being performed once: at the initialization of the `height` and `width` fields. After changing the `x`'s and `y`'s, you need to repeat the calculations for the `height` and `width`, to update their values.

Ex:

```
x2 = 55;
width = x2 - x1;
```

When performing a math calculation, the variable's values are only used once. Once the calculation is done, (`height = y2 - y1`), the `height` variable does not relate to the `y2` and `y1` variables.

---

***Solution:*** Manually update the `height` and `width` values, by repeating the calculation, when the `x`'s and `y`'s values are changed.

***Solution example:***

```
public void setX1(int x1) {
    this.x1 = x1;
    height = x2 - x1;
}
```

Or an even better example is not to have the `height` and `width` fields, and use this:

```
public int getHeight() {
    return y2 - y1;
}

public int getWidth() {
    return x2 - x1;
}
```

Comment: Why downvoted? Please tell me if there is anything bad about this answer, and I will fix it, thanks.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you could be more clear towards why the calculations are done only once, like Andy Brown did in his answer.

Comment: I didn't down vote but your last getters are wrong: no return type, wrong expression

Comment: Thanks for the help people, I really appreciate it.